# return decimal with two decimal places C#

Tags: c#, grid, rounding

I'm trying to round decimal values with two decimal places, e.g. I have 57,328385899814471243042671610 and I want 57.33.

```
     for (int i = 1; i < cobtable.Columns.Count; i++) //loop para preencher a linha das percentagens
        {
            Decimal a = (Decimal)cobtable.Rows[2][i];
            Decimal b = (Decimal)cobtable.Rows[0][i];
            cobtable.Rows[3][i] = Decimal.Divide(a, b) * 100;

           // Decimal c = (Decimal)cobtable.Rows[3][i];

          // c = (a / b) * 100;

          //  c = Math.Round(c,2);

           Response.Write((Decimal)cobtable.Rows[3][i]);
           Response.Write("*");
        }

       GroupGrid.DataSource = cobtable;
       GroupGrid.DataBind();
```

the `c` variable gives me on `response.write()` the correct value but in the grid it doesn't show the same value, it shows 57,328385899814471243042671610. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why is the `Math.Round` line commented out? (although this doesn't set the value of the row)

Comment: can u share your grid query

Comment: `cobtable.Rows[3][i] = Math.Round(Decimal.Divide(a, b) * 100, 2);`

Comment: It does not show me the rounded value anyway @Sayse

Comment: Done! I used Steve's answer lol so easy.. Thank you all and thanks @Steve

Answer (score 0):

Use following method:

```
 Math.Round(57.328385899814471243042671610,2);
```

second parameter is no of decimal places

Comment: The OP already has, although commented it out. Suggesting that it didn't work for them as expected

Comment: @Sayse You're overlooking the decimal in the answer. OP has a comma.

Comment: @Sriram - The OP has a comma in the string, not in the double literal.

Comment: @WaiHaLee So the answer depends upon what culture OP is using.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.Math.Ceiling(c * 100) / 100);
```

Something like this would probably work.

Answer (score 0):

Specify a [`DateFormatString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.dataformatstring(v=vs.110).aspx) for the column in question in your `GridView`.

```
DataFormatString="{0:F2}"  // Rounds to 2 decimal places
```

This affects how the value appears to the user, without causing actual data loss from rounding.

Comment: I used this cobtable.Rows[3][i] = Math.Round(Decimal.Divide(a, b) * 100, 2); and gave me the values I want